# Firebase Hosting Rewrite to Cloud Function Prompting for Login

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm having some trouble with serving some dynamic content from *Firebase Hosting*.

I've written an `http.onRequest()` cloud function that returns an image (content-type: image/jpeg) as its response. The function works as expected if I access it directly at its url:

`https://us-central1-my-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/hosting-getPartnerImg`

Per the documentation, I am using the `us-central1` region.

I would like to be able to invoke this function using Firebase Hosting as well, which I've configured as follows:

**firebase.json (snippet)**

```
"rewrites" : [
{
    "source" : "/pimg",
    "function" : "hosting-getPartnerImage"
}
],
"headers": [ 
{
    "source": "/pimg",
    "headers": [ {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=60"
        },
        {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
        } 
    ]

}]
```

**index.js (snippet)**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

let firebaseDefaultConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

admin.initializeApp(firebaseDefaultConfig);

const fn = process.env.FUNCTION_NAME;

if(!fn || fn === 'hosting-getPartnerImg'){
    exports.hosting = require('./hosting.js');
}
```

**hosting.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.getPartnerImg = functions.region("us-central1").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const partnerId = req.query.partner;
    const fileName = req.query.file;

    res.set("content-type", "image/jpeg");

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    let file = bucket.file("partnerImgs/" + partnerId + "/" + fileName);
    let readStream = file.createReadStream();
    readStream.pipe(res);

});
```

This one has me stumped. Navigating to a URL like:

`https://my-project-id.web.app/pimg?partner=BLAH&file=foo.jpg` does not generate a *Page Not Found* as other URLs, so I'm reasonably confident that the rewrite is taking hold as it should. Be that the case though, why am I immediately taken to:

`appengine.google.com/_ah/loginform...` with the message:

** An application is requesting permission to your Google Account **

Can't HTTP `onRequest` cloud functions be used anonymously via Firebase Hosting? Why does the function work when I hit it directly, yet requests permission when I access it via the Firebase Hosting rewrite.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `index.js` in this case?  Is it the source that is in the public directory?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that you actually have deployed a cloud function that works called `hosting-getPartnerImg` and show the code for that?

Comment: @robsiemb `index.js` is in the functions directory. I put it in as a snippet as it has many statements similar to the conditional shown to segment individual functions into groups. When this pattern is used, the `process.env.FUNCTION_NAME` becomes `hosting-getPartnerImg` rather than `hosting.getPartnerImg`, so yes, I have deployed that function, and it is working fine if I access it directly.

Comment: OK, I can't deploy a function with this source code / name pattern with the firebase SDK to replicate, are you manually creating this (either via gcloud or the cloud console or some other mechanism?).  I ask because the login page behavior is what happens when the function being called doesn't exist (regardless of if it is via a rewrite or not).

Comment: @robsiemb I'm deploying this as: `firebase deploy --only functions` and `firebase deploy --only hosting`. I get a message about a successful function creation/update and I can execute the cloud function from the `cloud functions.net` url without issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I have it now, the `!fn` was the trick that I omitted (as the environment variable does not exist during deployment).

Comment: @robsiemb Correct. For other curious, this approach is to help with cold boot times, and is outlined in the [Firebase Docs on Function Groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deploy_specific_functions)

Comment: @robsiemb I got it! First, I moved the `getPartnerImg` function out of the `hosting` group. No dice. Then, I changed the name from `getPartnerImg` to `getpartnerimg`, and it worked! It was the character casing! You were right about it not being able to find the function - it couldn't, due to the fact that I had camel-cased the function name. Took forever to crack. Thanks for providing a crucial hint! Many thanks!

Comment: We raced, but yes, the issue is the mismatched function name.  (Also, your rewrite was calling `hosting-getPartnerImage` not `hosting-getPartnerImg`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AppEngine login page behavior is what happens when the function being called doesn't exist (regardless of if it is via a rewrite or not).

Your problem is this rewrite:

```
"function" : "hosting-getPartnerImage"
```

vs the actual function name:

```
if(!fn || fn === 'hosting-getPartnerImg'){
```

or

```
exports.getPartnerImg = ...
```

Notably, the rewrite doesn't call the correct function.

You should change the rewrite to call `hosting-getPartnerImg` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was so focused on the assumption that I was missing some auth setting because it seemed like the rewrite was working. Thanks for picking up on the fact that I hadn't paid enough attention to the actual function name.